# Стратегии в LiveData. Реализуем MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

Хочу реализовать MVVM при помощи LivaData.

Есть экран Splash.

Состояние экрана

```
sealed class SplashState {
    object Loading : SplashState()
    object LoadingSuccess: SplashState()
    object Error: SplashState()
}
```

в `ViewModel` есть состояние

```
private val state: MutableLiveData<SplashState> = MutableLiveData(SplashState.Loading)

fun state() = state as LiveData<SplashState>

//некая операция
init {
    interactor.getData()
            .subscribe({
                state.value = SplashState.LoadingSuccess
            }, {
                state.value = SplashState.Error
            })
}
```

В Activity подписываюсь на состояние

```
splashViewModel.state().observe(this, Observer { 
            when (it){
                is SplashState.LoadingSuccess -> {
                    //бла бла прошел 
                }
                is SplashState.Error -> {
                    //открываем Toast ошибки
                }
            }
        })
```

Как выходить из ситуации когда Error нужно показывать только один раз? Например, произошла ошибка, показали Toast с ошибкой и больше эта ошибка не будет приходить пока не возникнет еще раз (т.е. если перевернули экран эта ошибка уже не придет).

p.s. Это абстрактный пример, в место Error может быть что то другое.

Comment: Для таких событий, как показ сообщений в Snackbar или навигации используйте observable вроде SingleLiveEvent.

Comment: обычно делают класс-обёртку `Event`, который следит, были ли получены данные из него. Вот статься, в конце есть код такого класса https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150